How to solve non-ideal opamp circuit using feedback properties?
Is there a neat way to solve this using feedback properties? Or if you know a better method to solve this, please suggest one.

It would be straightforward if we assume an ideal opamp in this case, but I want to solve it exactly. I know how to solve this using nodal analysis or superposition, but I'm looking for an alternative approach which may be more intutive and less math.
The result from my analysis  for \$ V_{out}\$ using superposition is:
$$V_{out} = \frac{\left( -A_v\frac{ R_{in}}{R_{in} + R_{out}} + \frac{ R_{out}}{R_{in} + R_{out}} \right) V_{fb}}{1 + A_v\frac{ R_{in}}{R_{in} + R_{out}}} $$
where \$ V_{fb}\$ is the 1mV voltage source.
When I substitute the values, I get -0.9999750006mV, which matches the simulation as well.


@RussellH Thanks, I just corrected the mistake when I typed LaTeX.

Interesting problem. It's effectively not possible to check with SPICE and might be running into machine epsilon issues even with double precision.
I assign Vx to the node before Rout, and Vin to the inverting input voltage and get:
Vx = Vout + Vin(Rout/Rin)
Vx = -Vin*Av
Solve for Vin as a function of Vout
Vin = Vout + V1
Solve for Vout
I get Vout = \$\frac{-V1}{1 + 1/k}\$
where k = Av + Rout/Rin
Which works out to approximately:
Vout = -0.99997500062502812320312070637688 mV
Pay attention to dimensional analysis and do some back-of-envelope calculations to help confirm your answer (or change the numbers to ones that are not as realistic such as Av = 20, Rout = 1000 Rin = 2000 to get a simulation that can be compared).
You can see that most of the error is the order of 1/Av and the error due to the loading is not only the order of 1/Av^2 (and Av >> 1) but also has a ~ 140/2E6 factor so it's really, really tiny.
Needless to say, I've shown a stupid number of decimal places, so this is purely a theoretical exercise and checking. The input offset voltage of a 741 will change a few uV during warm-up (at least) which is many orders of magnitude greater than the slight loading contributes.

Could you explain how you got the first equation?

The current from the output Iin= Vin/Rin. The voltage drop across Rout is In*Rout.

I see, your method is good as well but I'll wait if there is an answer using feedback something like Vout/V1 = 1/(feedback factor)*T/(1+T) where T is the loop gain.
